# Bitcoin, is this for real or not?

Tags: electrum

My sister in law believes she has bitcoin, I think she may have something also but do not know for sure, [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there some way to safely prove that you control a certain number of Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93870/is-there-some-way-to-safely-prove-that-you-control-a-certain-number-of-bitcoin)

Comment: Frankly, I have sincere doubts that you would have 250,000 bitcoins without knowing for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely, but you can find out easy enough whether it’s real: create a wallet on your own phone (e.g. bluewallet.io for Android or Blockstream Green for iOS) and try to send 1 ₿ from your SIL’s phone to your new wallet. If you receive the 1 ₿, congratulate your SIL to an early retirement:
250,000 bitcoins are currently worth $17,500,000,000, i.e. seventeen-and-a-half billion USD.

However, I would be surprised if someone were to own 1/80th of all bitcoins in existence without knowing whether they have any bitcoins at all. I suspect that the app or website you are looking at is either a watch-only wallet that follows some exchange’s wallet, or outright malware that is showing you bogus. Either way, the most likely explanation is that what you are seeing is the outcome of someone trying to scam your SIL, likely to extract an [advance fee](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406).